# Thunderbird 3.0.2 stops automatically checking for email

Tags: macos, mac, email, thunderbird

Since upgrading to Thunderbird 3.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.6, Thunderbird will intermittently stop checking for messages automatically.  Frequently I am presented with the error "This folder is being processed" when manually checking for mail.

Restarting Thunderbird fixes the problem, but I have noticed hours can go by where auto checking isn't working, and restarting shows there were dozens of messages waiting to be delivered in that down time.

Occasionally I will see "indexing 1 of 2 messages - 0% complete" in the status bar, it will sit there for a long time.

Actions I've taken to fix:

Deleted all .msf files in all accounts

Removed News & Blogs account

Staggered the "automatically check for mail" interval for each account

Worth noting: after waking up the macbook, TB usually needs to be restarted to resume auto checking for mail.

Has anyone experienced such trouble?

Answer (score 1):

So far it seems that 3.0.3 has fixed the problem.